# How to add a new category to a deep learning model?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Say I have done transfer learning on a pre-trained network to recognize 10 objects. How do add a 11th item that the network can classify without losing all the 10 categories that I already trained nor the information from the original pre-trained model ? A friend told me that active research is going on in this field, but I can't find any relevant papers or a name by which to search for ?

Thank you.